# C#: Custom IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, ienumerator

This is a message pertaining to C# in Unity, but I'm assuming general C# knowledge will apply.

Take the following code:

```
class myClass
{
    IEnumerator myEnumerator;
    public IEnumerator theEnumerator()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Debug.Log(i++);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (myEnumerator == null) { myEnumerator = theEnumerator(); }
        myEnumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

If I instance that class, then call "Update" once per frame, I get the following output in the log:

```
0
1
2
3
4...
```

That works fine, however I want to implement some custom functionality in the IEnumerator itself. But if I create the following:

```
public class myIEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    public int myCustValue;
    public void myCustFunction(){}
}
```

and then update the oringal class, replacing "IEnumerator" the "myIEnumerator", I get the following error:

```
The body of `myClass.theEnumerator()' cannot be an iterator block because `myIEnumerator ' is not an iterator interface type
```

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I make my own custom IEnumerator?

Comment: I think this is a compiler thing and the compiler supports only `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerator`, and `IEnumerator<T>`. Inheritance doesn't work for iterator blocks.

Comment: It's in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx), "Iterator Methods and get Accessors

The declaration of an iterator must meet the following requirements:

    The return type must be IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator, or IEnumerator<T>.

    The declaration can't have any ref or out parameters."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `yield` within a method whose return type is `IEnumerator`, `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerator<T>`, or `IEnumerable<T>`.  You can't change the return type of the method to a type that implements one of those interfaces, that doesn't make sense.

The reason for this is that the C# compiler generates a special class that implements one of those 4 interfaces (actually it implements both `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable` or the generic versions thereof) and an instance of that compiler generated class is what actually gets returned from the method.  By changing the return type you're trying to say that the compiler will create an instance of your class that will do the enumeration.  But it can't do that, because it doesn't actually know anything about your class (and in fact your class might not even enumerate correctly).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Unity but I think you have to implement the `IEnumerator` interface. The methods `MoveNext()`and `Reset()`are missing.

Have a look at the [IEnumerator Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.collections.ienumerator(v=vs.110).aspx)